# How can i verify if a button was pressed in run time?

Tags: vb.net

If you know anything please help me, thanks :)
I have two buttons that open the same form.
this form has a gridview that when selecting the line will display the data in different textbox according the clicked button.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you using WinForms of WPF? How are you opening the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the buttons use different event handlers you already know what button was clicked.
If they are using the same click event handler, you can use the Sender to find out the button that got clicked, like this:

```
Dim ButtonName as string = CType(Sender, Button).Name
```

Then all you have to do is pass the ButtonName to the second form and do your stuff there.